# Unable to schedule crystal report on crystal server and destination as email?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

I can schedule crystal server and destination as `FTP` or BI inbox but while configuring destination as Email , getting an error as scheduled failed.

How Can I resolve this error ?

Comment: You need to provide more details. We can schedule and email reports on our Crystal server. If it fails, you should try sending e-mail that server via the mail server. There are some command line based e-mail programs like BLAT.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install *Stunnel Proxy* in your Crystal server. By default it doesn't support email as a destination.

After that, you can configure it in `core server--> adoptive job server`. You'll need to set up basic configuration like the domain name, email id, and password.